# Sound Frequency and Healing

Tags: sound, frequency, sound-art

I was wondering if anyone new about the phenomenon of frequency and brain healing. I got a call from someone who is doing an art installation and wants to use the frequency or frequencies which could be responsible for healing neuro synapses. She mentioned that it is around 523Hz to 574Hz.

There is not much on this except for a few esoteric sites which I am skeptical of.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, this MAY be possible, but I doubt it. Brain healing just does not sound like a sound question...

Answer (score 1):

try this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binaural_beats

have fun creating this nice tunes ;)

Comment: Exactly what I though of as well Andreas. I would just like to add my $0.02 to this: The binaural beats "phenomenon" is fact (similar to optical "illusions") but no scientifically sound study (excuse the pun) has ever linked binaural beats to any kind of healing or beneficial health effects. That does not mean that music or sound in general doesn't have positive effects on our well-being, we all know it does, but in the case of healing specifically through binaural beats ...well let's just say to indeed be very, very skeptical :)

Comment: I have very interessting experiences with learning in dedicated frequencies. I think it works very well but maybe its just placebo. But hey. If it works, it's right. Isn't it !

Answer (score 0):

A guy used to show up on the REAPER forum talking about this sort of thing. I don't think he's still around but you may be able to find the old threads with a bit of searching.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether audio "brain healing" is an actual thing, you can use steady and modulated frequencies to induce mildly altered states of consciousness. Some people experience these states as pleasant, others as unpleasant. Either way, the effect is subtle enough that you probably won't be able to consciously detect it unless you are an experienced meditator or have otherwise made an effort to develop an awareness of subtle mind states.

FM synths are a great way to play with these frequency effects. You can start out with sine waves and easily dial up and down the harmonic content. Ableton's Operator is perfectly adequate for the task, as is NI's FM8. The classic Yamaha DX series are also good choices, but you will want to look for a six operator synth like the TX802 rather than the four operator synths like the TX81z. The thing to look for is fine grained control over frequencies and envelopes - this is present in the six op synths but tends to be dumbed down in the four op synths. Also, the button pushing interface gives you very precise control compared to on-screen faders.

> There is not much on this except for a few esoteric sites which I am skeptical of.

In my experience, this is a *very* subjective area. Run some experiments on yourself to see if you notice anything. If you don't, then work closely with the installation artist to get it right. I wouldn't bank on any medically-verifiable healing going on, but mild and pleasant trippiness is very possible.